# Saver for Snapchat (PC) version 1.1.769.0 - JSON Issue

Tags: json

I have a problem with Saver for Snapchat (PC) version 1.1.769.0.

Everytime I try to log in, I get the following message:

> Failed to deserialize the JSON response: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path ”, line 0, position 0.

The same thing happens when I try to log in on a different computer.

I have been using this program for months without any problems.

Do you guys know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the server it's performing JSON requests against is returning improper/unexpected responses.

If you're using the latest version of Saver for Snapchat, then it may just be server failure (temporary or permanent).

If you're not using the latest version, they may have changed the format of the responses recently, and your old version doesn't recognize it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have installed the program on a third computer and tried to log in, but I get the same message.